# Show Android App Widget in all homescreens

Tags: android, android-widget

I am developing an android widget to show in the homescreen. Now, I can show the widget in main homescreen. Now, is there any way to show that widget every homescreens (in most of the devices there are several homescreens where we can swipe to left or right from the homescreen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the user manually adds your app widget multiple times.

Comment: then there is no way to do set the widget for all homescreens!

Comment: @gypsicoder: Correct. Please allow your users to use their device as they see fit. If they have a device with "several homescreens", and they want copies of your app widget in each, they are perfectly capable of doing that themselves.

Answer (score 0):

These depends on entirely on the home screen app.  Some home screen apps could certainly implement a UI to have a widget like this.  The launcher that is part of stock Android does not have such a facility.